# UICollectionView items not showing after migration to Swift 2

Tags: uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, swift2, ios9, xcode7

After migrating my Xcode 6 project to Xcode 7, only the first `UICollectionView` in my app renders properly.

When I switch tabs the CollectionView doesn't render properly.

**The app worked fine in iOS 8.**

*Example:*

1. Here is a CollectionView header in the Storyboard.

   [image: Header]
2. When I run my app, I am getting a blank view.

   [image: Result]
3. Interestingly enough, when I use the View Hierarchy debugger, it
   shows that the element in fact does exist.

   [image: View Hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like ios9 has a bug when rendering custom cells.

I would suggest creating your custom cells in xibs and then loading them from there.

Make sure to include this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SongCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SongCell")

self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SongHeader", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SongHeader")
```

Comment: Darn, we can maybe do a screen share sometime if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add this line in viewDidLoad of your collectionView controller

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(YourCustomMemeClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Comment: Interesting pattern, but Swift 2 isn't too fond of it unfortunately, I'm getting ambiguous reference to member.